# how to modify /etc/resolv.conf as non root user in docker file or as script

Tags: docker, dockerfile, root

Based on best practice and recommendation we should always run docker container as non root user for security reason. While doing so I am facing one issue where I have to override */etc/resolv.conf* file with domain name. I am appending domain name in resolv.conf file via script e.g. env.sh (I am calling this script as e.g.
The Dockefile has following command

```
from dabian:latest
... 
...
ENTRYPOINT[env.sh]
```

The script `env.sh` simply append domain name based on environment e.g *dev/qa/prod etc.*

If I run docker container as root user there is no problem as the *resolv.conf* will get updated with appropriate domain name map (based on environment profile) but if I add non root user (in docker file ) and use the user and call `ENTRYPOINT[evn.sh]` , the *resolv.conf* file will not get updated.

Is it because the files like hosts or *resolv.conf* inside docker get always override by host configuration and only root are allowed to modify these file (which apparently looks like).

My question is , Is it possible to do same as non root user or is there a way to grant non root user just enough permission to modify *resolv.conf* and yet run as non root user (may be scoping or limiting user privilege to just modify resolv.conf ) ? Has anyone come across this scenario ?

Answer (score 0):

you have two options:

run your `container` as `root` and run your `application` using another user in your `ENTRYPOINT` using:

```
runuser -l YOUR_USER -c "COMMAND_TO_RUN"
```

or setting up passwordless `sudo` and assign the user to it , something like this in `Dockerfile`:

```
RUN adduser YOUR_USER sudo
RUN sed -i.bkp -e \
      's/%sudo\s\+ALL=(ALL\(:ALL\)\?)\s\+ALL/%sudo ALL=NOPASSWD:ALL/g' \
      /etc/sudoers
```

Comment: after running this command I am getting "sed: can't read /etc/sudoers: No such file or directory" . I tried adding permission in /etc folder but didn't work.

Comment: You need to install sudo at first